# Packer cannot find file when it is there

Tags: vagrant, packer

I'm trying to run `packer validate ./Vagrant/windows_7.json` from my home directory C:\Users[User]\ but it is failing in the scripts section with the error `The system cannot find the path specified`. I can use the Fully Qualified path and it works fine but it doesn't work for relative for some reason. Is there anything in the config that indicates why the system cannot find the file? It's weird because it can easily find the ./iso/Windows_7.iso perfectly fine but not the vagrantfile-windows_7.template and the scripts. The packer directory looks at everything relative to the .json build file right? I've tried checking permissions too but my Username has full access rights. I also have the latest Packer 0.10.1 for Windows.

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "iso_url": "{{user `iso_url`}}",
      "iso_checksum_type": "{{user `iso_checksum_type`}}",
      "iso_checksum": "{{user `iso_checksum`}}",
      "headless": true,
      "boot_wait": "2m",
      "ssh_username": "vagrant",
      "ssh_password": "vagrant",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "8h",
      "shutdown_command": "shutdown /s /t 10 /f /d p:4:1 /c \"Packer Shutdown\"",
      "guest_os_type": "Windows7_64",
      "disk_size": 61440,
      "floppy_files": [
        "{{user `autounattend`}}",
        "./scripts/dis-updates.ps1",
        "./scripts/hotfix-KB3102810.bat",
        "./scripts/microsoft-updates.bat",
        "./scripts/win-updates.ps1",
        "./scripts/openssh.ps1",
        "./scripts/oracle-cert.cer"
      ],
      "vboxmanage": [
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--memory",
          "2048"
        ],
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--cpus",
          "2"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "remote_path": "/tmp/script.bat",
      "execute_command": "{{.Vars}} cmd /c C:/Windows/Temp/script.bat",
      "scripts": [
        "./scripts/vm-guest-tools.bat",
        "./scripts/vagrant-ssh.bat",
        "./scripts/disable-auto-logon.bat",
        "./scripts/enable-rdp.bat",
        "./scripts/compile-dotnet-assemblies.bat",
        "./scripts/compact.bat"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "keep_input_artifact": false,
      "output": "windows_7_{{.Provider}}.box",
      "vagrantfile_template": "vagrantfile-windows_7.template"
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "iso_url": "./iso/Windows_7.iso",
    "iso_checksum_type": "SHA1",
    "iso_checksum": "36AE90DEFBAD9D9539E649B193AE573B77A71C83",
    "autounattend": "./answer_files/Autounattend.xml"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when running packer to build the json template not being in the same directory as it takes your current directory and not the json template directory

```
C:...>cd Vagrant
C:...\Vagrant> packer validate windows_7.json
```

In your template you reference the script `./scripts/dis-updates.ps1` and the script is located under `C:/.../Vagrant/scripts/dis-updates.ps1` but when packer validates your template it takes your current directory not the directory when the template is located.